# Replacing and Editing Objects in a Tableview. (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm having trouble with setting up my Table View.
I have a TableView "Entries" where there will be a list of my entries.
I have a seconds TableView "AddEntry" where I have a couple of Textfields, which will define properties of an Object. After I press "Add" the object Name is shown in the "Entries" TableView.

Here comes my Problem: I want to be able to edit the Objects property afterwards by clicking on it's row.

So for example:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:kEditSegueIdentifier]) {

    edited = YES;

    AddEntry *controller = [[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    EntryObject *entry = self.entryObjectArray[self.indexPathInt];

    controller.property1 = entry.property1;
    controller.property2 = entry.property2;
    controller.property3 = entry.property3;

    }
}
```

This will later fill up the textfields in the "AddEntry" view with the selected Objects Properties. So far so good.

If I now (with or without changing the objects properties) click "Done" this Method will be called and it will create a new Row with a new created Object, which is the exact same as the one I wanted to edit.

```
- (void)saveEntryDetails:(EntryObject *)entry {

if (edited == YES) {

    [self.entryObjectArray replaceObjectAtIndex:self.indexPathInt withObject:entry];
}

[self.entryObjectArray addObject:entry];

if (self.entryObjectArray.count < 1) {

        NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.entryObjectArray count] inSection:0]];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else {
NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.entryObjectArray count]-1 inSection:0]];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  }
}
```

How can I distinguish between "Object was newly created" and "Object was edited"?

Also how do I replace that edited Object in my Array?

Answer (score 0):

create an entryObjectCompareArray as original array, then compare to entryObjectArray,

```
NSMutableArray *leftArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:entryObjectCompareArray];
[leftArray removeObjectsInArray:entryObjectArray];
```

leftArray will be the edited object and others are newly created.